# Modificar modo oscuro del navegador de Samsung

Tags: html, css, samsung

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una web estática básica para un asunto personal. La cosa es que en todos los navegadores en modo oscuro se muestra bien porque tengo habilitado lo siguiente:
`<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">`

A mayores he probado a usar la query `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {` pero en este navegador de samsung parece que nada afecta.

Alguien podría ayudarme indicándome como puedo evitar que me cambie los colores el navegador de Samsung en modo oscuro.

Comment: ¿Has verificado si es una característica [soportada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme#browser_compatibility) por dicho navegador?

Comment: Es verdad que el only light no lo soporta pero no hay alguna manera de que no me cambie todos los colores?

Comment: El enlace que te compartieron en el otro comentario te indica que pruebes con `color-scheme` que sí está soportado. Probaste? Qué pasó?